# How to handle PHP session variable names for two instances of application running on same server?

Tags: php, session

For example let's say I have an app that uses `$_SESSION['user_id']`. Now if I have two of these applications running on the same server then they will be sharing this user_id variable which would break things.

The only thing I can think of is to prepend some unique id like this:

`$_SESSION['/app1/user_id']`

`$_SESSION['/app2/user_id']`

is that the best option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the purpose of [`session_name()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.session-name.php).  Assign a different name to each application's session to avoid collisions between `$_SESSION` keys. The name will be used as the session cookie's name so although both session cookies will be passed to both applications, only the one matching the application's `session_name()` will be used to populate `$_SESSION`.

```
// App 1
session_name('app1');
session_start();

// App 2
session_name('app2');
session_start();
```